# Laravel Eager Load Constraint issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Edit: For clarity, this is Laravel 5.8.

This is for a HR app I'm working on.

They requested a report to show people who have punched in late. Sure, no problem I thought.

So I have a form with some custom parameters the user can punch in, start_date, end_date, wage, and an array of departments.

```
public function show()
{
    request()->validate([
        'start_date' => 'required|date|before_or_equal:today'
    ]);

    $start = Carbon::parse(request('start_date'));
    $end = request('end_date') ? Carbon::parse(request('end_date')) : today();
    $wage = request('wage');
    $departments = request('departments');

    $query = EmployeePunch::with([
        'employee' => function($query) use ($wage, $departments) {
            // IF I UN COMMENT THESE, IN THE FILTER BLOCK BELOW, THE EMPLOYEE BECOMES UNDEFINED.
            // if($wage != null) {
            //     $query->where('hourly', $wage);
            // }

            // if($departments) {
            //     $query->whereIn('department_id', $departments);
            // }
        },
        'employee.group',
        'employee.department'
    ])
    ->whereBetween('punch_time', [$start->startOfDay(), $end->endOfDay()])
    // only care about punch in for the day
    ->where('type', 1);

    $results = $query->get();

    $latePunches = $results->filter(function ($i) {
        $day = strtolower($i->punch_time->format('D'));
        $startTime = Carbon::parse(sprintf('%s %s', 
                                            $i->punch_time->format('d-m-Y'), 
                                            $i->employee->group[$day.'_start_time'])
                    );

        return $i->punch_time->isAfter($startTime) 
                && $i->punch_time->diffInMinutes($startTime) >= 5;
    });

    return view('hr.employeeLateReport.show', compact('latePunches'));
}
```

So, my problem is in my eager loading and I can't figure this out. If I uncomment the filters in the eager loading of employees, in the filter block near the end of the code block, the `$i->employee` becomes undefined. If omit the filters, everything works peachy. I've checked the queries being produced and it all looks great.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the relationship methods

### Employee.php

```
public function punches()
{
    return $this->hasMany(EmployeePunch::class);
}

public function group()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Group::class);
}

public function department()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Department::class)->withDefault();
}
```

### EmployeePunch.php

```
public function employee()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class);
}
```

### SQL Output

[image: sql]

Comment: Did you check the existance of data for those queries?

Comment: Yes. I found each query via the laravel debug bar and ran them through the database directly and they all work as expected.

Comment: uncomment the inner query and then try with `whereHas('employee', function($q) {});` and inside `whereHas` filter using `whereBetween`

Comment: What happens when you take the other nested relations inside `employee.group` and `employee.department`? Try `$query->with('group')->with('department')` inside the `employee` closure.

Comment: @FarrukhAyyaz can you please post an answer. Your comment led me to a working result. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try and use `whereHas` and nest `whereBetween`:

```
$query = EmployeePunch::with([
    'employee' => function($query) use ($wage, $departments) {
        if($wage != null) {
            $query->where('hourly', $wage);
        }

        if($departments) {
            $query->whereIn('department_id', $departments);
        }
    },
    'employee.group',
    'employee.department'
])->whereHas('employee', function($q) use($start, $end) {
    $q->whereBetween('punch_time', [$start->startOfDay(), $end->endOfDay()]);
})->where('type', 1);
```

Comment: So if `punch_time` is an employee field, then how is `$i->punch_time` working?

Comment: we have checked that, if we have in relation `employee` then we can process employee attributes

Comment: So you are saying, if we have a relationship defined, we can call the fields of relationships like `$model->relationships_field`?

Comment: `punch_time` is an `EmployeePunch` field. The `EmployteePunch` has an `employee` relation. If you eager load, or lazy eager load the relationship you can access the related model.